# Storing Videos in Web Application or Otherwise

Tags: video, storage

I'm looking to let users of my web application upload videos to my site, however i believe i will be constrained by how much storage i will actually have. Is there any alternatives such as being able to store videos on Youtube via the api and recall them when needed. Any help for the design of how videos should be stored would be great.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) storage, however I think it will end up being rather expensive.

Answer (score 0):

How much video are you thinking of using? You can buy huge drives fairly cheaply now. I'd try to store it on-site if possible rather than going through a 3rd party... You'll have much easier access to the data and will be able to change the structure as you want.

It's hard to recommend any method of storage without details of how the site will be used. i.e. are all videos 'owned' by a registered user, or are they all communally owned etc??